# Arrange data frame with multiple columns + rank column

Tags: r

I have sorted a data frame with arrange function (dplyr)

[image: DATA FRAME]

How can I add a column that shows the rank of the data frame  ? ( without jumping any number)

for example

row 2 and 3 are exactly same  so both have rank 2

row 4 and row 5 are same in column A and B **but are different  in column C** so

row 4 : rank 3
row 5: rank 4

Comment: checkout dense_rank from dplyr

Comment: Thank you . But it didn't work . dense_rank can take only a vector for ranking . I want to rank  a data frame

Comment: Please make it easier for people who are trying to help you. Don’t add data/code as images. Provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

You can paste all the values rowwise and use `match` to create `rank` column. If your dataframe is called `df` try :

```
vec <- do.call(paste, c(df, sep = '-'))
df$rank <- match(vec, unique(vec))
df

#  X1 X2 X3 X4 rank
#1  1  2  3  4    1
#2  4  5  6  7    2
#3  1  2  3  4    1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(1L, 4L, 1L), X2 = c(2L, 5L, 2L), X3 = c(3L, 
6L, 3L), X4 = c(4L, 7L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean to rank the dataframe as a whole by `apply`ing some summary measures to the columns such as `sum`. That measure can be `rank`ed:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  c1 = runif(10),
  c2 = sample(100:1000, 10),
  c3 = rnorm(10),
  c4 = sample(1:10, 10)
)

df$rank <- rank(-apply(df, 1, sum))
```

Result:

```
df
          c1  c2         c3 c4 rank
1  0.2875775 962  1.2240818  2    1
2  0.7883051 508  0.3598138  4    6
3  0.4089769 709  0.4007715  9    4
4  0.8830174 614  0.1106827  3    5
5  0.9404673 192 -0.5558411  1    9
6  0.0455565 906  1.7869131  6    3
7  0.5281055 320  0.4978505  5    8
8  0.8924190 137 -1.9666172 10   10
9  0.5514350 392  0.7013559  8    7
10 0.4566147 951 -0.4727914  7    2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cur_group_id` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(across(everything())) %>% 
    mutate(rank = cur_group_id()) %>% 
    ungroup
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#     X1    X2    X3    X4  rank
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     2     3     4     1
#2     4     5     6     7     2
#3     1     2     3     4     1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(1L, 4L, 1L), X2 = c(2L, 5L, 2L), X3 = c(3L, 
6L, 3L), X4 = c(4L, 7L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```